# I want to push data into a binary tree, but it is showing a segmentation fault after 3 inputs

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

This is a push function to enter data into a binary tree.  It is causing a segmentation fault on the third call. Check out the code for more.

```
void push(){
  int data;
  printf("enter the data you want to enter");
  scanf("%d",&data);
  struct bst* temp;
  temp=(struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst*));
  temp->data=data;
  if(root==NULL){
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    root=temp;
  }else{
    struct bst* p;
    p=root;
    while(p->left!=NULL || p->right!=NULL){
      if(data<<p->data){
         p=p->left;
       }else{
         p=p->right;
       }
    }
    if(data>>p->data){
      temp->left=NULL;
      temp->right=NULL;
      p->right=temp;
    }else{
      temp->left=NULL;
      temp->right=NULL;
      p->left=temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This line `temp=(struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst*));` is wrong.  You are accidentally allocating the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure.

Comment: Also, someone is bound to turn up and tell you not to cast the result of `malloc`...

Comment: ... indeed: do not cast the result of `malloc()` in C code.  But this case is a bigger problem than the usual, inasmuch as the explicit cast might inspire greater, *yet misplaced*, confidence that the resulting pointer actually points to space large enough for at least one `struct bst`.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but do you see how *in every alternative* you set `temp->left` and `temp->right` to `NULL`?  The code would be a bit easier to write, analyze, and maintain if you did that at the top, in conjunction with setting `temp->data`, instead of at three different places according to the specific case.

Comment: Aside: I tried to fix the indentation in the while loop, but SO claimed the edit didn't have the required minimum 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you are traversing the tree, you are using `p->left!= NULL OR p->right!= NULL` condition. In this case if your tree's left is not NULL in this case you are assigning NULL to p. Then you are comparing data with NULL variable data. This causes to segmentation fault. You need to add AND statement instead of OR to the while condition:

`while(p->left!=NULL && p->right!=NULL){`

Also in this line `if(data>>p->data){` you are using right shift operator instead of greater operator. You should type it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with the code presented, some of which have been presented in comments and in another answer.  Among these are

- You do not allocate enough space for each node (per @EddInglis).  As a result, you write outside the bounds of the allocated object when you set one or more of its members, thus producing undefined behavior.  **This is likely the source of the segfaults**.  As an associated but secondary matter, in C, you do not need to explicitly convert values of type `void *` to other object pointer types for assignment, and as a matter of style and good programming practice, you should not do so.
- Your conditional logic for traversing the tree is incorrect (per @hhusein).  The condition `p->left!=NULL || p->right!=NULL` holds for all nodes that are not leaves, but you need also to accommodate the case of internal nodes that have only one child.  This probably *is not* the cause of the segfault, though.  It is just prone to losing data and leaking memory.
- Your conditional logic for choosing which direction to move in the tree is incorrect:

  > ```
  >    if(data<<p->data){
  > ```

  ...

  > ```
  >  if(data>>p->data){
  > ```

  The `<<` and `>>` operators compute bitwise left and right shifts.  You are looking for relational operators instead (`<` and `>`).  This is not responsible for your segfault, but it will cause the resulting binary tree to fail to be a binary *search* tree.  The nodes will be arranged incorrectly in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are three typos in your code,

1. Your `malloc` is allocating size of  pointer than a node. i.e malloc(sizeof(struct bst))
2. `if(data<<p->data)` is left shifting data than comparing. Replace to just comparison `if(data < p->data)`
3. `if(data>>p->data)` is right shift operator and you need `if(data>p->data)`

Apart from the typos, logic to find the right place holder for new created node has to be fixed.

```
temp->left= NULL;
temp->right= NULL;
while(p){
    if(data < p->data){
       if(!p->left) {
           p->left = temp; 
           break;
           }
         p=p->left;
    }else if(data > p->data) { 
       if(!p->right) {
           p->right = temp; 
           break;
           }
       p=p->right; 
    }else{
       //Skip insertion for same key
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @eddinglis As I look closely I'm finding more